# Wicket: double login required due to extended browser info

Tags: java, wicket

I have a Wicket 8.6 application. Currently, when logging in to the application, mostly (does not always happen) the user has to login twice. After the first login (after entering the credentials and clicking the submit button) a white page appears saying "If you see this, it means that both javascript and meta-refresh are not support by your browser configuration. Please click this link to continue to the original destination." This is the BrowserInfoPage. After a few seconds the user is redirected to the login page again where he/she has to enter his/her credentials again and press the login button. This time, the user logs in successfully. My question is, how do I prevent that the user hast to enter his/her credentials twice.

From my research I know that it has something to do with the collection of extended browser info. In the init method of my WicketApplication class, I had the following code:

```
getRequestCycleSettings().setGatherExtendedBrowserInfo(true);
```

However, I already commented out this code several month ago. For some reason, the described effect occurs for every new deploy now. Maybe a newly added package in the application is the reason for it. I don't know. Is there a possibility to prevent this second login maybe by creating a customized bowser info page which forwards the login? Please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find any location in Wicket's source (except examples, including wicketstuff) setting that flag.
Please create a quickstart showing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I did some more testing and I could not reproduce it on my local system (except when I set setGatherExtendedBrowserInfo to true). It only occurs on the server and only for the first login. Thus, I could not reproduce it in a quickstart. After some research I come up with a work around (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I came up with a work around. It is probably not very efficient but it works for me so far. In my custom Session class which inherits from AuthenticatedWebSession, I added the following code.

```
    @Override
    protected WebPage newBrowserInfoPage() {
        final Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
        if(request.getUrl().toString().contains("LoginPage")) {
            if(!isSignedIn()) {
                signIn(username, password);
            }
            PageParametersEncoder encoder = new PageParametersEncoder();
            PageParameters parameters = encoder.decodePageParameters(request.getUrl());
            String url = parameters != null && parameters.get("originUrl") !=null && !parameters.get("originUrl").isNull() && !parameters.get("originUrl").isEmpty()?
                    parameters.get("originUrl").toString("pages/home"):"pages/home";
            String finalUrl=url.startsWith("pages/")?url.substring("pages/".length()):url;
            throw new RedirectToUrlException(finalUrl);
        }
        return super.newBrowserInfoPage();
    }
```

Some explanation to the code. As mentioned in the question, I want to prevent the user from logging in multiple times. Thus, I check if the request comes from the LoginPage and perform my work around only in that case.
During my implementation, I realized, that the method newBrowserInfoPage is called in the process when I call `session.signIn(username,password);` on my LoginPage. In this signIn process the authenticate method of my custom Session is called but the signedIn flag in the AuthenticatedWebSession is not changed (keeps false on successfull authentication). Is this a bug? Thus, I have to login again to set the flag to true.
Finally, I read the URL of the LoginPage where I have stored the target URL and forward the user to the target URL.
I am aware this is probably not the best approach but it is the only solution I came up with. If someone has a better idea, I am happy to hear it.